# remove password from lots of .dotx files

Tags: powershell, ms-word, passwords

I tried this script in ms editor to remove password from dotx files in my explorer. The script runs without warning, but nothing happens. protection ist still included.

I have lots of documents to change and hope you can help me.

i tried this script:

```
$path    = '"path folder with dotx files"'
$passwd  = 'pASSWORD'
$counter = 0
$WordObj = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$WordObj.Visible = $false

# get the .dotx files. Make sure this is an array using @()
$documentFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.dotx' -File)
foreach ($file in $documentFiles) {
    try {
        # add password twice, first for the document, next for the documents template
        $WordDoc = $WordObj.Documents.Open($file.FullName, $null, $false, $null, $null, $passwd)
        $WordDoc.Activate()
        $WordDoc.Password = $null
        $WordDoc.Close(-1) 
        $counter++
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Could not open file $($file.FullName):`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }

}

Write-Host "Finished: $counter documents of $($documentFiles.Count)"
```

Comment: addition: the document can be opened without password, only editing of the files is protected

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: Perhaps you need to also _save_ the document.

Comment: i got this error message:  Could not open file D:\....dotx: Ausnahme beim Festlegen von "Open": Der Wert "Password" des Typs "string" kann nicht in Typ "Object" konvertiert
werden.

Comment: Sounds like a parameter-type mismatch, though it's strange that it wouldn't accept a password as a _string_. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Documents.Open) aren't of much help - they list the type of the various password parameters as `Variant`.